# Prevent window from losing focus

Tags: python, windows

Hi i want to control a game window with SendMessage() or PostMessage(), but the window always loses focus when I am clicked out of it or alt tabbed. One solution was to keep the window focused via:

```
 win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd).
```

But the thing is I want to control multiple instances of the game and this way I can only control the one focused.

I i can somehow prevent the window from losing focus i can freely use SendMessage() or PostMessage() to control multiple instances.

The game lacks option for setting it to Borderless Fullscreen (which works in many cases)

Also FYI game window regains focus when tabbing into it, or hovering with a mouse onto it.
It loses the focus when i click out of it.

I don't know if there is some way to prevent it from losing focus.

Thanks in advance.